# removeFromSuperView with Page View Controller

Tags: ios, uibutton, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol, removechild

I'm trying to close a Page View Controller with IBAction button, I can close the view (PageContentViewController), the new view (LoginViewController) is showing but the "dots" from Page Control are still here, and I can't communicate with the new view (LoginViewController).
What am I doing wrong ?

Here is my code :

LoginViewController.h :

```
#import "PageContentViewController.h"
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageTitles;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageImages;
@end
```

LoginViewController.m :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
        // Create the data model
        _pageTitles = @[@"Over 200 Tips and Tricks", @"Discover Hidden Features", @"Bookmark Favorite Tip", @"Free Regular Update"];
        _pageImages = @[@"FIRST_img.jpg", @"FIRST_img.jpg", @"FIRST_img.jpg", @"FIRST_img.jpg"];

        // Create page view controller
        self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

        PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
        [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];



        // Change the size of page view controller
        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

        [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
        [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
        [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    }


- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

    return pageContentViewController;
}


#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return [self.pageTitles count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}
```

PageContentViewController.h :

```
@interface PageContentViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property NSUInteger pageIndex;
@property NSString *titleText;
@property NSString *imageFile;
- (IBAction)dismissButton:(id)sender;
@end
```

PageContentViewController.m :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imageFile];
    self.titleLabel.text = self.titleText;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)dismissButton:(id)sender {
    [self.view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromParentViewController) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];


}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You remove PageContentViewController but not PageViewController (it is still there). 
Try to use in dismissButton method [self.view.superview ...

Edited:

The good way is to remove the parent from the parent with the standard code:

```
   [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];  
   [self.view removeFromSuperview];            
   [self removeFromParentViewController];
```

But you want to do it as you do, remove parent from the child then try to use code like:

```
   [self.parentViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];  
   [self.parentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];            
   [self.parentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
```

or [self.parentViewController.parentViewController ...  it depends on hierarchy.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for replying ! I've replace "[self.view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];" with "[self.view.superview performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];" but it's the same problem... :(